# extract sub dataframe loc in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having problem in slicing a total Pandas dataframe into subsets and then join them in a for loop. 
The original dataframe looks like this:

[original DataFrame content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQXFT.png)

*Forgive me that I blocked out some details to avoid issues on data security/policy. As long as the message is conveyed.

This is a query problem that I need to query for each "Surveyname" from another list which contains the survey names, and output to a table of all surveys (in sequences of the list) and their other information from selected columns.
The original Dataframe has columns of these:

```
Index(['Surveyname', 'Surveynumber', 'Datasetstatus', 'Datasetname',
   'Datasetprocessname', 'Datasetdatatype', 'Datasetseismicformat',
   'Datasettapedisplay', 'Inventoryid', 'Inventoryname',
   'Inventorybarcode', 'Inventoryremarks', 'Datashipmentnumber',
   'Facilityid', 'Facilityname', 'Inventoryfullpathfilename',
   'Inventorytype', 'Mmsdatasetname', 'Inventorymediatype',
   'Inventoryoriglocation', 'Inventoryreceiveddate',
   'Inventorydataattribdesc', 'Firstalternatedesc', 'Secondalternatedesc',
   'Thirdalternatedesc', 'field26', 'field27', 'field28', 'field29',
   'field30', 'field31', 'field32'],
  dtype='object')
```

And I am selecting only these columns as output:

```
cols =['Surveyname','Surveynumber','Datasettapedisplay','Inventoryid','Inventorybarcode','Inventoryoriglocation']
```

I set up an empty dataframe at the start and try to append the "queried" subset dataframe to this one. Hope it will grow along with the for loop. 
The code looks like this :

```
f=open('EmptySurveyList2.txt','r')
cols =['Surveyname','Surveynumber','Datasettapedisplay','Inventoryid','Inventorybarcode','Inventoryoriglocation']

setdf=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)# create an empty DataFrame

for line in f:
    print(line)
    # check by string content
    df0=df_MIG.loc[df_MIG['Surveyname']==line,cols]
    print(df_MIG.loc[df_MIG['Surveyname']==line,cols])
    # check by string length for exact match
    df0=df0.loc[df0['Surveyname'].str.len()==len(line),cols]
    print(df0.loc[df0['Surveyname'].str.len()==len(line),cols])
    print('df0:',len(df0))

    setdf=setdf.append(df0)
    print('setdf:',len(setdf))
```

However, this code would still give me only a few rows from the very last survey on the 'setdf' dataframe.
I went on debugging. I found that in the for loop, the df0 dataframe is not finding the survey information from the main `df_MIG` for the first N surveys in the list except the last one. By printing out the lenth of the `df0` and the `setdf`:

```
>...Centauro
>
>Empty DataFrame
>Columns: [Surveyname, Surveynumber, Datasettapedisplay, Inventoryid, 
>Inventorybarcode, Inventoryoriglocation]
>Index: []
>Empty DataFrame
>Columns: [Surveyname, Surveynumber, Datasettapedisplay, Inventoryid, 
>Inventorybarcode, Inventoryoriglocation]
>Index: []
>df0: 0
>
>setdf: 0
>
>Blueberry
>
>Empty DataFrame
>Columns: [Surveyname, Surveynumber, Datasettapedisplay, Inventoryid, 
>Inventorybarcode, Inventoryoriglocation]
>Index: []
>Empty DataFrame
>Columns: [Surveyname, Surveynumber, Datasettapedisplay, Inventoryid, 
>Inventorybarcode, Inventoryoriglocation]
>Index: []
>df0: 0
>
>setdf: 0
>
>Baha (G)
>    Surveyname Surveynumber Datasettapedisplay Inventoryid Inventorybarcode  \
>219   Baha (G)       329130                FIN     1538554          4210380   
>
>Inventoryoriglocation  
>219  /wgdisk/hn0016/mc03/BAHA_329130/MIGFIN_639_256...  
>    Surveyname Surveynumber Datasettapedisplay Inventoryid Inventorybarcode  \
>219   Baha (G)       329130                FIN     1538554          4210380   
>
>Inventoryoriglocation  
>219  /wgdisk/hn0016/mc03/BAHA_329130/MIGFIN_639_256...  
>df0: 1
>
>setdf: 1
```

While if I do the query outside of the loop,

```
a = "Blueberry"
df0=df_MIG.loc[df_MIG['Surveyname']==a,cols]
df0=df0.loc[df0['Surveyname'].str.len()==len(a),cols]
setdf=setdf.append(df0)
```

It works normal and no issues, found the rows which has the name of the survey and add it to the `setdf`
[Bebugging outside loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64zjM.png)

This is quite a mystery to me. Anyone can help clarify why , or suggest a better alternative ?

Comment: You are appending outside of the loop, so you only ever append the very last value of `df0` to `setdf`. Instead, initialize an empty list above the loop `df_list = []`, within the loop append to the list `df_list.append(df0)` (this way you record `df0` on EVERY ITERATION) and then outside of the loop create the DataFrame with a single concatenation. `set_df=pd.concat(df_list)`

Comment: Sorry I did not edit the code block correctly, The `set_df=set_df.append(df0)` is actually in side the loop. I am seeing that over the iteration that `df0` did not got updated correctly. That the `len(df0)` is zero, which should have found some rows and contain non-empty dataframe. And that is why my final set_df is very short. Like 3 rows something (should found more than 100 rows). If the `df0` updates I will certainly try the `pd.concat` you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: I realized that the file read in had a '\n' next line at every line until the very last one. That '\n' got included and resulted in a mismatch except the very last line. Once I split the string and take out the '\n', code works perfectly.